# Mapping different https subdomains to different ECS containers on same application load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I'm using the [Docker ECS integration](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/) to deploy an app and a webservice it depends on. Both should be running over HTTPS, at different subdomains.

My problem is, both need to run over HTTPS but since the ECS docker thing only created one load balancer, it looks like I can only configure it to forward https traffic to one target group. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you add the HTTPS listener to the load balancer, set the default rule to forward to one of the target groups (probably the main web app). But then go back to the list of listeners and click "View/edit rules". You can then add a Host Header rule for each additional service. The host header just equals the domain name, including subdomain, e.g. `service-A.example.com`. That way one HTTPS listener can handle every subdomain on the same application load balancer. The documentation for this is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html).

Note: If HTTP and HTTPS listeners aren't available, you may have accidentally created a network load balancer. This happens when at least one of your services exposes a port other than 80 or 443. To [force it](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-compose-features/#exposing-ports) to be an application load balancer (which will let you forward HTTP and HTTPS traffic), your docker-compose config needs to look like this:

```
  test:
    image: mycompany/webapp
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        x-aws-protocol: http
```